# How to find if an apex:inputField is disabled

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

From a VisualForce controller, how can I find if a dependent pick-list inputfield is disabled?

There does not seem to be an accessible 'disabled' property for the field.  I am creating validation to make sure fields on a visualForce page are filled out. I do not want to do the validation on the dependent pick-list when there are no values to select, and it is in a disabled state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a dependent picklist is required and no values are available for it based on the controlling field value, users can save the record without entering a value. The record is saved with no value for that field. [Dependent Picklist Considerations](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm)

if its required jest on your page:

```
public boolean StateDisabled {get;set;}
  <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="StateDisabled" style="display:none"  value="{!StateDisabled}" />
<div>
 <apex:inputField value="{!con.Mailing_Country__c}" onblur="StateDisabled();" />
</div>              
<div Class="State"> 
 <apex:inputField value="{!con.Mailing_State_Province__c}" onchange="StateDisabled()"  />
/div>
<script>
    function StateDisabled(){
        $(".StateDisabled").attr('checked',true);
        if(!$(".State select").attr('disabled')){
            $(".StateDisabled").attr('checked',false);
        }
    }
</script>
```